# Wordpress NextPage tag gives unwanted post pagination on home page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm building a Wordpress child theme on their stock twenty-eleven theme on a private test server.

I'm using <--nextpage--> to paginate long posts, and it works beautifully on my single post pages, but my problem is that it also shows the pagination on the home page excerpt for the paginated post, which I don't want. This happens even though the <--nextpage--> tag appears later than the <--more--> tag in my post.

Any ideas how to disable the post pagination on my home page while retaining on my single-post page?

Many thanks,

Donal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the nextpage quicktag before but - from what I understand, at least - in order for a given post to understand that the quicktag needs to be converted to page links, you need to have [wp_link_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_link_pages) called somewhere within the given loop.

If that's the case, then you'll need to create a copy of the twentyeleven/content-single.php file and place that within your child theme.

On line 24 you should see this:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
```

Try changing it to this:

```
<?php
if(!is_front_page())
    wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) );
?>
```

This is untested, and quite honestly I've never put the nextpage tags to use before so I don't really know for certain if this will achieve what you want. But give it a try and let me know how it all works out.

Comment: Thank you kindly maiorano84 -- that did the trick. I had to modify the code in content.php rather than content-single.php, as it seems that the former controls the home page, rather than the latter, but you got me most of the way there and saved me a lot of messing around. Big thanks, and Happy New Year to you! Donal

Comment: And you as well! I'm glad you got it all sorted out. If you can, please mark this as answered in case other people have a similar question.